# Flutter-unable to set coordinates in line charts?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm facing issues in line charts. i'm fetching x and y data from sq lite database. and it should set 
in line chart.when activity started chart showing blank. but only click on chart value is setting in 
chart. 
i'm using charts_flutter dart package for implementation.
where i did the mistake. any solutions.

```
Future graph_initialize()  {
Future<List<Map>> noteListFuture1 = dbHelper.get_lactation_curve("${widget.value.tag}");//fetching data from databse
noteListFuture1.then((noteList)  {
  for(int i=0;i<noteList.length;i++){
    print(noteList[i]["Days"].toString()+","+noteList[i]["Milk_Yield"].toString());
    milking_data.add( new Sales(noteList[i]["Days"], noteList[i]["Milk_Yield"]));
  }
_serieslineData.add(charts.Series(
    colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.red),
    id: 'lac',
    data: milking_data,// here data is setting
    domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
    measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval));
  setState(() {

  });

});}

@override
 void initState() {
super.initState();
_serieslineData =  List<charts.Series<Sales, int>>();
graph_initialize();//function call
}

Widget show_chart(){
return Padding(
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
 child: Container(
   height: 300,
   child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text('Lactation Curve',
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
       Expanded(
           child: charts.LineChart(_serieslineData,
               animate: false,
               domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                   tickProviderSpec:
                   new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
                     desiredTickCount: 11,
                   ),
                   viewport: charts.NumericExtents(
                     0,
                     300,
                   )),
               animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
               behaviors: [
                 charts.ChartTitle('Milk Yield',
                     behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.start),
                 charts.ChartTitle('Days in Milk',
                     behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom),
                 charts.ChartTitle(
                   '',
                 ),
                 charts.ChartTitle('                           ')
               ])),
       Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         child: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
           children: <Widget>[label(Colors.red,'Lac'),
             label(Colors.lightBlueAccent,'Milk(kg)'),
             label(Colors.amber,'A.I'),
             label(Colors.green,'Pregnant'),
             label(Colors.blueGrey,'Vaccination'),
             label(Colors.black,'Treatment'),

           ],
         ),
       )
     ],
   ),
 ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `bool loading or isLoading` to control because chart data is not ready yet 
and when loading == true return `CircularProgressIndicator()` or `Container()`

```
bool loading = false;

Future graph_initialize()  {

loading = true;

Future<List<Map>> noteListFuture1 = dbHelper.get_lactation_curve("${widget.value.tag}");//fetching data from databse
noteListFuture1.then((noteList)  {
  for(int i=0;i<noteList.length;i++){
    print(noteList[i]["Days"].toString()+","+noteList[i]["Milk_Yield"].toString());
    milking_data.add( new Sales(noteList[i]["Days"], noteList[i]["Milk_Yield"]));
  }
_serieslineData.add(charts.Series(
    colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.red),
    id: 'lac',
    data: milking_data,// here data is setting
    domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
    measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval));
  setState(() {
     loading = false;
  });



});}


Expanded(
       child: loading?  CircularProgressIndicator() : charts.LineChart(_serieslineData,
           animate: false,
           domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
               tickProviderSpec:
```